# Struts 2 value stack "Login attempt" counter not persisting variable

Tags: struts2, persistent-storage, valuestack

I am learning Struts 2 now and trying to make a login attempt counter to block any further login attempts after x failed attempts.

Here is the body of my login.jsp

```
<body>

<h1><s:property value="loginAttempts"/></h1>

<s:form action="login">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="Username" />
    <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
<%-- <s:hidden name="loginAttempts"  value="<s:property value="loginAttempts"/>" /> --%>
    <s:set var="loginAttempts"><s:property value="loginAttempts"/></s:set>
    <s:submit value="login"/>
</s:form>

</body>
```

And my Action class (I am not including the private var w/their getters and setters but they are all there)

```
public String execute() throws Exception{

    if (username.equals("admin")&& password.equals("admin"))
    {   return SUCCESS;}
    else if (Integer.parseInt(getLoginAttempts())>2)
    {
        return "lockout";
    }
    else
    {   setLoginAttempts(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(getLoginAttempts())+1));
        return "fail";}
}
```

In the action that initially calls the login.jsp I pass in an intitial value

```
loginAttempts="0";
```

and that works fine. The problem comes when i hit submit on the login.jsp page.

I get the following stack trace

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
com.struts.users.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:17)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Line 17 is

```
else if (Integer.parseInt(getLoginAttempts())>2)
```

And every time i hit the submit button the `loginAttempt` variable it resets itself to `NULL`.

Thanks

Edit: I understand that this probably isn't the right way to be doing this and i should probably be doing this with sessions. However I am trying to understand why it isn't working.

Comment: If you don't post the value, there won't be one. The attempt count should be stored in session (if you don't care about closing down the browser, opening, and starting all over), or in app context, or in the DB, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "post the value"?

Comment: ... Post the value. It's a form, it gets posted (or GETted). Things not in the form (like `<s:set>`, which is only useful for the duration of the request) don't.

Comment: A different angle... JSPs of course are interpreted on the server side. The set tag allows you to assign the value of an expression to a variable. Like in java you would say: `int x = y + 1;` once you hit the end of the method x is out of scope... same with the set tag, once the server is finished rendering the page the value assigned in the set tag goes out of scope. The set tag is a convenience so you don't need to keep writing long expressions over and over and lets you make things more readable. (you can set the scope of the var too)

Comment: If you set the s:set vars scope attribute to session or application you might get the result you are looking for... I don't think this is a good idea but when learning it would be a short cut to "results".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A struts2 action is not persistent! It is recreated each and every time the request happens.
What you need to do is implement the `ServletRequestAware` interface for the action which will give you access to the `HttpServletRequest`, you can then obtian the http session object stored by your webserver and increment the value on that. Be careful as this will need to be threadsafe - you may need to lock the http session while updaing the value.
Another approach would be to have an object in the `ServletContext` that stored a `Map` of username to login attempts. This may be more reliable.


A bit of clarification from comments:

Your form sends (known as POSTing) the values on it to your webserver, struts2 then takes this 'POST data' and interprets it for you - using the relevant setters on your action to make this data available to you.
So, in order to send the login attempts value your form needs to have it as a variable, hence the need for an `<s:hidden>`. Your action should then have a setter for loginattempts; i.e. a method with the signature `setLoginAttempts(int loginAttempts)`.
Now, when your action is done and finds that the request is invalid you want to increment that variable and provide a getter for it in the action.
Now your JSP, which is rendered by the action on a failed attempt, can read that value off the action and add it to the HTML form that the user will send. Hence my reference to a circle.
This method will not do anything to add to the security of your website as the variable `loginAttempts` is read from the user POST data - the user can send anything it wants and your action will read that as the number of login attempts.
I hope that helps...

Comment: Not by IP address, because many people may be mapped to a single IP, for example, by their ISP or company.

Comment: Fair point - but it's fairly hard to determine that some request comes from the same point. Http session is all good and well but easily resetable...

Comment: I understand that the action is not persistent. But I am passing the value to the jsp. It is being stored by <s:set var="loginAttempts"><s:property value="loginAttempts"/></s:set>. Wont that value get placed back in the new value stack when the submit button is subsequently pressed again?

Comment: you're calling s:set, this puts the value on the [ValueStack](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ValueStack.html). This is no more persistent than the action - it lives in the actioncontext.

Comment: See Dave's comment on your original question - you need to persist this information somewhere.

Comment: `<s:textfield name="username" label="Username" /> <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>` both work to update the new value stack. Why shouldn't `<s:set var="loginAttempts"><s:property value="loginAttempts"/>` do the same?

Comment: or `<s:hidden name="loginAttempts"  value="<s:property value="loginAttempts"/>` for that matter?

Comment: They are sent every time the page is submitted. If you want to send the loginattempts in 'a circle' you can use something along the lines of `<s:hidden name="loginAttempts" value="loginAttempts"/>` and provide a getter/setter in the action. This will not be at all secure as the user can simply send a different value...

Comment: @BLam85 Using a hidden value *would*, but obviously using nested tags would fail for syntax; just the name is enough. The problem is that if you do any redirects etc. it will be cleared if you don't persist it anywhere. Allowing the user to spoof the value, though, negates the purpose. `<s:set>` does nothing of value for you here, because the value stack is *also* per-request.

Comment: ok, thats how i had it originally `<s:hidden name="loginAttempts"  value=loginAttempts />`. but that gives me a error `quote symbol expected` and if i try putting in quotes like `<s:hidden name="loginAttempts"  value="loginAttempts" />` then it reads it in as a string `"loginAttempts"`.

Comment: Oh, and or course you need to use OGNL sytax, i.e. `<s:hidden name="loginAttempts" value="%{loginAttempts}" />`

Comment: @bmorris591 YES!! That was it. `value="%{loginAttempts}"`